# Need to collect list<String> empName using string

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class `employee` which has `empName` and `empSalary`.  I need to get the list of `empName` whose salary is greater than certain value using java stream.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<Employee> elist= new ArrayList<>();
    
    Employee e1 = new Employee("kaustubh",1001234123);
    Employee e2 = new Employee("kaustubh2",100);
    Employee e3 = new Employee("kaustubh3",10055);
    Employee e4 = new Employee("kaustubh4",100234);
    Employee e5 = new Employee("kaustubh5",10054);
    
    
    elist.add(e5);
    elist.add(e2);
    elist.add(e3);
    elist.add(e4);
    elist.add(e1);

    List<String> ename = new ArrayList<>();
    ename = elist.stream().filter(i -> i.getSalary() > 10054).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ename = elist.stream().filter(i -> i.getSalary() > 10054).map(Employee::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you. Both the solutions working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map(Function<T, R>)` to map the stream to another value.

```
List<String> ename = elist.stream().filter(i -> i.getSalary() > 10054).map(Employee::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add getName() method in Employee class if it is not exist.
You can do it by multiple ways

1.Using Method referencing

`ename = elist.stream().filter(i -> i.getSalary() > 10054).map(Employee::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());`

2. Using lambda Expression:

`ename = elist.stream().filter(i -> i.getSalary() > 10054).map(e-> e.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());`